# How to make a thread that is getting a simultaneous requests by other threads and it needs to flush them out one by one

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

So, I am using a midi controller to move the mouse for controlling a program purposes.
My problem right now is that I hit the mouse with multiple instances of robot class (maybe a very bad idea) for example if I move 2 faders together in my current code I'm generating 254 instances of robot and the mouse is getting half way at both on - screen faders.

My question is: is there a way to keep a list of the requests and flush them out one by one. Also the list/queue must be able to fill it's back side while flushing

EDIT: the list/queue must also flush the requests as soon as it receives one

If you can just point me to the right direction that would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Why not simply use a `BlockingQueue`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the queues from `java.util.concurrent` package, [ArrayBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) for example.

Also to mention. 
You say: "the list/queue must also flush the requests as soon as it receives one". A list or a queue itself does not flush anything. It's up to threads to decide when they are ready to get another request from a queue.

Comment: Thank you for the correction this clears things up a bit